# How to $.post to Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code js and php

```
$.post("url.php", {
        'action': 'add'
    }, function (data) {

  do something here with the data

});
```

and for the php I have sometinhg like this:

```
$action = $_POST['action'];

if($action == 'add'){
    do something here
}
```

My question is - How do I do the same but for Node JS?

Thanks

Comment: First page of the express documentation ... :/

Answer (score 1):

`$ npm install express body-parser --save`

`$ touch ./index.js`

```
// in index.js
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express()
// or .json() depending on your preference
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  if(req.body.action === 'add') {
      return res.send('Hello World!')
  }
  return res.send('Action not supported'); // or 404 or whatever. 
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

`$ npm start`

Then, in a webpage

```
$.post("/", {
        'action': 'add'
    }, function (data) {

  console.log(data); // should be "Hello World!"

});
```

Comment: Seriously? This is not an answer.

Comment: How not?  It's precisely answering his question.

Comment: no it does not contain `$action = $_POST['action'];

if($action == 'add'){
    do something here
}` And copy + pasting a sample code is *not* an answer

Comment: Ok, added the action bit.  Feel free to add your answer if you have a better way to explain it.